# Train with YOLO pretrained weights on Darknet

Tags: tensorflow, yolo, darknet, pre-trained-model

I'm attempting to train my Yolo object detector using the Darknet CNN. I'm using Yolov4 pre-trained weights which can predict Cars, Traffic Lights, and Stop Signs with these COCO Classes. Just wondering how I can add an extra layer so my model can also pick up Traffic Signs. Code below to train:

```
!./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/yolov4-obj.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -dont_show -map
```

Google Colab I'm using as reference: [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_GdoqCJWXsChrOiY8sZMr_zbr_fH-0Fg?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to train the model from the beginning with images of all previous objects, Cars, Traffic Lights, and Stop Signs, in addition to the new Traffic Signs.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing. Using the yolov4.conv.137 pretrained weights, I trained it with Cars, Traffic Lights, Stop Signs, and Traffic Signs. My Traffic Sign MAP was the lowest which makes sense. Thank you!